# A specific embedding of semisphere on $R^2$.

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, isometry

I was playing with piece of paper which has the form of semisphere, to be more precise we may assume that it satisfies $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ for nonnegative $z$. I tried to make it flat without stretching and cutting, just by bending. I couldn't perform this action, so I decide to write this problem mathematically:

Let $S \subset R^3$ be a space of all points satisfying previously defined equation. There is a natural metric $d'$ on this set, which is not induced by euclidian metric on $R^3$, but it is the length of the geodesic curve between 2 points. I 'm searching for continuous injection $f$ from $S$ to $R^2$ preserving  metrics(i.e. $d'(a,b)=d(f(a), f(b))$.

Intuitively there is no such map. But I'm wondering about related more general theorems. I haven't taken differential geometry yet, and I don't know which tags would be more appropriate, so feel free to edit. Even if there is no related theorem, I'm interested in the proof of this specific problem. But again, feel free to answer anything related.

Comment: If there was such mapping, there would not be such trouble with earth representation . See https://xkcd.com/977/ ;)

Comment: @stity Wonderful analogy! :)

Comment: Enquiring minds want to know: How did you get a piece of paper shaped liked a hemisphere...?

Comment: @Andrew Ok. Actually it was connected subset of ellipsoid -- the wrapper of kinder-surprise. I hope the problem has become more clear now :)

Comment: My guess was paper wrapped around an orange or something.... ;)